# How to animate an imageview (when page is scrolled up) to merge in smaller imageview in Toolbar

Tags: android, animation, material-design

Initially an image will be shown having upto 1/3 of screen height and full screen width. (android.support.v7.widget.)Toolbar will be gone.

I want to animate ImageView (when page is scrolled up) to be part of Toolbar and make the toolbar visible. While scrolling down reverse action should happen.

**Edit:**
Similar animation can be found here. There is a minor change though, the image of giraffe will move on the toolbar and appear between left arrow and text "item 4". The animation has to be like Shared view or Hero view but on the same activity.

http://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/

How can this animation be done?

Comment: Any image for example?

Answer (score 4):

**Everything is simpler with the new  Android Design Library**

Build The Design Library Adding This Link In Your Gradle File

**compile "com.android.support:design:23.1.0"**

**You can achieve exactly this effect by following Below Code**

https://github.com/saulmm/CoordinatorBehaviorExample

http://blog.grafixartist.com/toolbar-animation-with-android-design-support-library/

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can achieve the functionality using the [CoordinatorLayout](http://antonioleiva.com/coordinator-layout/) which was launched in the new [Design Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#design).

Please check this example http://antonioleiva.com/coordinator-layout/

Comment: The link you have shared can scroll the toolbar upwards beyond visible area. I want to make it visible and show small sized image in toolbar when scrolled up. It will be similar to shared view animation except that it will happen in the same activity.